# Cannot access session state data on another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

I'm creating an inactivity check for my bot where it sends a message to the user if X amount of minutes have passed since the last message he sent.

```
bot.dialog('SomeDialog',
    function(session, args){
        let text = "The text sent to the user";
        session.send(text, session.message.text);
        check(session); //The function where I send the session to do the checking
        session.endDialog();
    }
);
```

The check function is where the problem happens:

```
check(session){
    if(!session.conversationData.talked){
        session.conversationData.talked = 1;
    }
}
```

When I run it, I always get

```
Cannot read property 'conversationData' of undefined
```

If I use `session.conversationData.talked` within the `bot.dialog` it works, but not on the `check` function.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code snippet works fine on my side, maybe you can provide your whole picture of your porject for further analysis.

However, to your requirememnt, you can consider to use the node package [`botbuilder-timeout`](https://github.com/user1m/botbuilder-timeout),

Comment: Thank you, I think that package is what I'm looking for. Still trying to figure why my code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an "async" timing issue. The session on your browser / server needs to be sync'd.

Is this JS server side, or browser side? And what framework is this intended for?